# Is it appropriate to caution someone "from" something?

Tags: grammar

Is the word "from" used appropriately in --

> The fact that ... has happened before and could happen again, should caution us from being ...

Or is it a colloquial sort of thing?

Specifically, I'm concerned about "caution us from" in lieu of "caution us away from" or some other idiom.

Comment: A century or two ago you might have *cautioned someone **of** [their dangerous circumstances]*, but that usage has largely fallen by the wayside today. Nowadays we mostly stick to *cautioning someone **against** [doing something dangerous]*. But we can also *caution someone [not] **to** [do something]*, and the syntax / popularity of that infinitive verb-based construction doesn't seem to have changed much over time (except maybe we're more likely to use ***advise*** rather than ***caution*** in many contexts today).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's appropriate, and it's not only colloquial. Consider this [1845 English translation](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hell_Opened_to_Christians/qKQPAAAAIAAJ?hl=en) of Pinamonti's *L'inferno aperto*, where the first part of the title is *Hell Opened to Christians to Caution Them from Entering into It*.

For a more modern example, consider this [informational publication](https://www.dhs.wisconsin.gov/publications/p02438.pdf) from the Wisconsin Department of Health Services, educating camp staff on how to keep campers safe: "Caution them from swallowing lake, river, or pond water and encourage them to shower off after swimming."

Granted, *against* and *about* are likely [more common](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/25-words-and-their-prepositional-pals/) in conjunction with this verb, but *from* as used in your question is not inappropriate.

Comment: Your answer is backed up by a Google nGrams search for ["caution against", "caution about", and "caution from".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caution+against%2Ccaution+from%2Ccaution+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaution%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaution%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaution%20about%3B%2Cc0)  (Other verb tenses yield similar results.)  Notably, "caution from" used to be more common than "caution about", with the prevalance shifting in the early 20th century.

Comment: I am inclined to think that there is regional variation in how common "caution from" is.  Certainly as a middle-aged native English speaker most strongly influenced by U.S. midwest and Southern usage, I would have been inclined to say that "caution from" is non-idiomatic

Comment: @JohnBollinger:  Interesting.  I'm a middle-aged native English speaker most strongly influenced by Western Canadian and US midwest usage.  To me it sounds "old-fashioned" or "British" (which I apparently conflate somewhat) but not ungrammatical.

Comment: I'm on board with John's regional variation hypothesis. I had the same intuitive response as Michael did, and I have a fairly similar English language background. I'm also middle-aged, born and raised in Central Canada, and have spent most of my adult life in the Northeastern US.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It's not British. Or, at least, it's not something that is used throughout Britain; it's possible that there are some places where it is used, but I've never personally heard it, and would consider it odd if I ever did.

Answer (score 7):

No, you caution *against* doing something.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/caution-against-sth) backs me up on this:

> caution against sth
>
> to tell someone that doing something is not a good idea:
>
> caution (sb) against sth/doing sth *Many economists caution against reading too much into one month's report.*

"Caution from sth" yields no results.  To my surprise, it appears some people do use this expression, based on other answers.  But I think we can say that "against" is the form recommended by reference materials.

Comment: Anything to support the no part?

Comment: @PhilSweet It sounded so strange to my ear that I didn't think to look it up, since obvious mistakes wouldn't be in any reference material. Apparently other people do use it though, judging by the other answer.

Comment: Dictionaries seem definitely to want "against" not "from", which surprises me. But supports Casey's answer.

Comment: @StuartF Indeed, just for laughs I looked up "caution from" in the same source and didn't find it, so I've updated the answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt/learned 'caution against'.

caution (somebody) against something or caution (somebody) against doing (verb + ing)

The fact that ... has happened before and could happen again, should **caution** us **against** being ...

Comment: This is an ELL level answer. EL&U values answers supported by authoritative reference, or at least well-reasoned argument. Take some time to peruse well-received answers and compare them to your attempts.